# Regex - search up till (but exclude delimiter)

Tags: regex

sorry i’m starting out with regex. appreciate if anyone help me with a syntax to extract `Apple Pie`

I have a string which is delimited by a semicolon `;`
Now I need to extract the section after `No_23">` but excluding the semicolon.

```
;abcde;No_22">123456;No_23">Apple Pie;No_24">New York;No_25">Qyt 4;>
```

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not totally clear what you're looking for. Why extract "Apple Pie" if you already know it's there? Or do you just want to know the position? Or, maybe you're looking to extract any thing between the `No_x">` and `;`. If that's it, something like `No_\d*">([^;]*);` might be what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex like

```
(?<=No_23\">)[^;]+
```

There is positive lookbehind `(?<=No_23\">)` and capturing characters other than `;` with `[^;]+`.

demo in python ->
https://regex101.com/r/IWauss/1

Answer (score 1):

> *'... I have a string which is delimited by a semicolon ; Now I need to extract the section after “No_23”>” but excluding the semicolon. ...'*

If you're looking for the value after "*No_23*" specifically, use the following.
This will assert that the preceding text is `No_23">`, and the succeeding text is `;`.

```
(?<=No_23\">).+?(?=;)
```

Or, if you want to match text after any of the "*No_*" values,

```
(?<=No_\d\d\">).+?(?=;)
```

Although, I presume the "*No_*" value may not always be 2 digits.
You can try using the `+` quantifier, I'm not sure if the *regex* *engine* you're using allows for it.

```
(?<=No_\d+\">).+?(?=;)
```

If not, as a final solution, just check for `\d\">`

```
(?<=\d\">).+?(?=;)
```

Here is the *Wikipedia* article on *regex*.
*[Wikipedia – Regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)*.

Comment: Small note, but `(?<=No_23\">).+?(?=;)` can still match `;` when there is `;;` due to the 1 or more times when using the dot https://regex101.com/r/X3q4hf/1

Answer (score 0):

Here it is, split string

;No_\d*">

[image]

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)  and explanation is missing how to get the unmatched string `Apple Pie` from this...